# Azure devops pipeline, powershell split string, convert to json and assign to pipeline variable doesn't work

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to convert a pipeline variable - delimited string - to a json array and assign the json array to an other pipeline variable. See my code below, output stays empty. What am I missing here?

script:

```
steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        $test = "LZ-UK;LZ-ES;LZ-NL"
        $json = $test.Split(";") | ConvertTo-Json -AsArray
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JsonLZ]$json"
        Write-Host "Assigned the variable"
        Write-Host "New `r`n $($JsonLZ)"
  - script: |
       echo ${{ variables.JsonLZ }}
```

output:

```
Starting: PowerShell
==============================================================================
Task         : PowerShell
Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.200.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/380b437f-74c4-4883-9d4a-7b4f3ac79266.ps1'
  "LZ-UK",
  "LZ-ES",
  "LZ-NL"
]
Assigned the variable
New 
 
Finishing: PowerShell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close. There were a few minor issues that I spotted with your YAML/PowerShell:

1. You forgot the semicolon after the variable name in `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=JsonLZ]$json"`, it should be: `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=JsonLZ;]$json"`
2. You should be using `$(JsonLZ)` instead of `${{ variables.JsonLZ }}`. The former will be evaluated at **runtime**, the latter at **compile-time**. Here's a link to the MS Docs: [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)

Give this a try to see a working example:

```
name: Stackoverflow-Example-Pipeline
trigger:
    - none
variables:
  JsonLZ: 'UNSET'
stages:
    - stage: StageA
      displayName: "Stage A"
      jobs:
        - job: example_job
          displayName: "Example Job"
          pool:
            vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
          steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              targetType: inline
              script: |
                  $test = "LZ-UK;LZ-ES;LZ-NL"
                  $json = $test.Split(";") | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
                  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=JsonLZ;]$json"
                  Write-Host "Assigned the variable"
          - script: |
              echo $(JsonLZ)
              echo ${{ variables.JsonLZ }}
```

Comment: Works as a charm, thanks. Next problem is when I try to pass the array to a template

- template: landingzones/general-landingzone.yml
    parameters: 
      landingzones: $(JsonLZ)
the pipeline response is: Actual value '$(JsonLZ)' instead of the array

Comment: Hm, you shouldn't need to pass that value between jobs. It is declared at the pipeline level, which will give all stages/jobs access to directly reference it, without passing it as a param.