# Azure pipeline parameter split doesn't work

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a mutli-step azure pipeline used to trigger the execution of a certain job based on keywords I have in azure devops work items.
First step executed is a powershell script that stores into a 'validTags' variable a comma-separated list of strings:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=validTags]$csTags"
```

After this step, I correctly see the list formatted as I expect:

```
string1,string2,string3
```

The 'validTags' variable is then passed as a parameter to another pipeline in which I should split this list and trigger separate jobs:

```
- template: run.yml
    parameters:
      tags: $(validTags)
      directory: 'path\to\tests'
      platforms: 'platform1,platform2'
```

In the 'run' pipeline I defined this 'tags' parameter:

```
parameters:
- name: tags
  type: string
  default: 'someDefaultValue'
```

and I try to split the parameter:

```
- ${{each t in split(parameters.tags, ',')}}:
    - script: |
        echo 'starting job for ${{t}}'
```

but when I execute the pipeline, I have in 't' still the full string (string1,string2,string3) not splitted.

I have noticed that if I try to perform the split on the "platforms" parameter which is passed along with "tags" to the run.yml pipeline, it works, so it seems that the problem is related to the fact that I am trying to split a string stored in an external variable?

Anyone with a similar issue? Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `${{}}` is *compile time* syntax. Parameters are resolved at *compile time*.

Setting variables during the pipeline run is, by definition, *runtime*. You can't use runtime values at compile time, because they **don't exist yet**.  You'll need to step back and more fully explain the scenario you're trying to implement, because as it stands, you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DanielMann - I have 2 yml pipelines. the first pipeline, there are 2 steps: 1. invoke the powershell script (in which the comma-separated valued are stored into the `validTags` variable) and 2. call the 'run.yml' pipeline passing the parameters shown above.
In the second pipeline I have a few steps, one of which should loop on the values stored in `validTags` - which I am trying to split.
I thought it could be a compile/runtime issue too, but I haven't found a workable solution, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Researched and found like similar issue of yours via this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71514067/azure-devops-pipeline-powershell-split-string-convert-to-json-and-assign-to-pi  you can refer to.

Comment: @RoyWang-MSFT thanks for the post, but I am still not able to get it work properly: instead of `${{each t in split(parameters.tags, ',')}}:` I tried also `${{each t in split('$(validTags)', ',')}}:` but I have the same issue then reading `t`.
For what I understand, reading here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split the syntax I am using to get each loop value is correct, but maybe I am misunderstanding it... 
Tried also to use `$(t)` but I get a string '$(t)' and not the value splitted...

Comment: @enricom Using macro syntax `$()` inside a compile-time expression (`${{}}` is **never** going to work. They are evaluated and exist in different phases of the pipeline's lifecycle. Here's a thought: Why do these tags have to be in a CSV file? Why can't they be defined in a YAML variables template that is used by your pipeline? Then the values actually *could* be made available at template compile time, and thus be available for looping?

Comment: @DanielMann the tags are coming as `TAG1,TAG2,TAG3` string from AZDO REST API; I am  just storing the string as-is into a variable `Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=validTags]$csTags"` and trying to use it in the pipeline template. What kind of different variable definition are you suggesting? 

Trying a workaround, I saw that if I call an Inline script in the template, doing:  `$tmp = $(validTags).Split(',')` I can see the values correctly parsed (just echoed them in pwsh), so I don't understand why looping in the pipeline itself won't split it :(

Comment: Do you understand the phases of pipeline template evaluation? Expressions in `${{}}` are evaluated *when the template is being compiled*. This is **before** the pipeline even starts to run. You can't mix compile-time expressions and run-time variables, because run-time variables *do not exist* when the template is being compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested in the outcome of this issue:

- I tested several possible alternate solutions, including the use of global variables and group variables, but without success.
- I submitted a request to MSFT engineering support to get some insight on this and their response is:

> The pipeline does not support splitting the runtime variable with
> template syntax ${{ }} currently, and we are not able to find other
> workarounds to meet your request. Sorry for the inconvenience. Hope
> you can understand.

So, to overcome the issue I removed the split at the pipeline level, as initially planned, but rather passed the comma-separated value's string to the template and added there the necessary processing in Powershell.

Another option would have been to perform all the operations from within the first PowerShell script step:

- transform the 'run.yml' template in a separate pipeline
- in the script, after getting the tags, loop over their values and trigger the 'run.yml' pipeline passing the single tag as a parameter.
  I avoided this solution to keep the operations separate and have more control over the execution flow.